# Cannot Find Transaction from Blockchain Explorer

Tags: transactions, withdrawal

I just withdrew some Bitcoin (BTC) from FreeBitco.in to this address:

1FCFLjBDk3BGbp2vtEPRNLcbGisZRUWfbV

My withdrawal was confirmed by the website an hour agao, and I received an email from FreeBitco.in showing [this link](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/tx/4b2f61842b8157953dda0595f5fe7249830b7316a39bed259e752345d64db240.) to view the transaction.

However, that link does not show any transactions at all. From my experience and all other information available online, FreeBitco.in seems legit. Why cannot I see the transaction from blockchain explorers? Is that because of the recent drop of hash rate?

Comment: You should not share your address or transaction details publicly. Maybe the transaction had some issues and got rejected after being broadcasted by their node. You need to contact them for support and request withdrawal again. It has nothing to do with hash rate.

Comment: @Prayank Thanks. I already received my coins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bulk transaction on 2020-09-05 at 02:07 transferred funds to a large number of recipients including 0.01546751 BTC to 1FCF...WfbV (34th recipient on that list)

See https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1FCFLjBDk3BGbp2vtEPRNLcbGisZRUWfbV

Maybe the transaction was initially included in a block that became extinct and the transaction was subsequently included in a later block? All normal.